# Fundamental Group Two Tori

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Leg $H$ denote the topological space obtained by gluing two tori together along a copy of $D^{2}$ that embeds in each. Compute a presentation for $\pi_{1}$? I tried finding the generators of each and then gluing them together

Comment: you mean a connected sum but with a disc inside. If it's what said, then you can shrink the disc and get the join of two tori $T^{2} \vee T^{2}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The magic words are  "van Kampen theorem." See [the wikipedia article for Seifert-van Kampen theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93van_Kampen_theorem).

Comment: Added that for you.

Comment: @tomasz why would it not let me?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: find a representation of $H$ as a cellular complex.